# Qt WebKit On Mobile

Tags: qt, mobile, qtwebkit

I am trying to render a web page. Qt says their QtWebKit is available for mobile since 4.8 [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-goes-mobile.html)

> If you want to target mobile devices you should consider using QGraphicsWebView instead of QWebView.

Both of them is under QtWebKit. So what am I missing?

Comment: Which mobile platform, specifically?

Comment: Android and iOS maybe WP8 too. Tried Android only.

Comment: No idea about WP8, but QtWebKit isn't available for Android or iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about Android and iOS, it's just a no-no. Citing Digia from the release page of Qt 5.2:

> Qt Webkit is **not supported** on **Android** and we are working on providing a cross-platform API to integrate web content into mobile apps. If you you would like to incorporate web content into your Qt application, you need to use a native web component. To make interacting with native contents easier, we are providing the [Qt Android Extras](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) module with a JNI convenience API.

The same goes for iOS where Apple explicitly forbids the usage of other WebKits, apart from their.

Digia is currently working on a [new web engine](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/01/23/qt-webengine-technology-preview-available/) which should be available on the Android platform (and embedded Linux) and it is now available in the [Qt 5.4 beta](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/10/17/qt-5-4-beta-available/#more-40509). The same policies issues of Qt webkit applies to the web engine, w.r.t. iOS.

To ease developers work, in the same new release Qt 5.4, Digia provides a technology preview of **Qt WebView**; citing again their blog:

> For platforms that do not allow distribution of Qt WebEngine as well as use cases where a full-blown web engine is not needed Qt 5.4 will introduce a technology preview of a new module called Qt WebView. It supports embedding the native web engines of the underlying operating system into Qt, and is currently available for Android and iOS. Because of this, Qt WebView also gives a convenient light-weight solution for simple web document integration. Qt WebView will be available with Qt 5.4 final as a separate add-on.