# Does Qt5.4 not support QtWebEngine?

Tags: android, qt, webview, qtwebengine

[image]Read from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785554/qt-webkit-on-mobile), I find that from Qt5.4, the Qt team will not support QtWebView, they said they will support QtWebEngine, but I could not find the header file from the installed folder, this is the output result:

```
  localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$ find ./ -iname "*QtWebEngine*"
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine_debug.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/5.4.1/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/5.4.1/QtWebEngine/private/qtwebengineglobal_p.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineDepends
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebengineglobal.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineVersion
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebengineversion.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngine_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine_debug.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore_debug.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWebEngineProcess
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Resources/qtwebengine_locales
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Resources/qtwebengine_resources.pak
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore_debug.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/5.4.1/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineWidgetsDepends
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineWidgetsVersion
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebenginewidgetsversion.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug.la
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/experimental/libqtwebengineexperimentalplugin.dylib
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/experimental/libqtwebengineexperimentalplugin_debug.dylib
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/libqtwebengineplugin.dylib
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/libqtwebengineplugin_debug.dylib
.//5.4/Src/qtdoc/doc/src/images/qtwebengine_quicknanobrowser.jpg
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/5.4.1/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/5.4.1/QtWebEngine/private/qtwebengineglobal_p.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/qtwebengineglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/QtWebEngineVersion
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/qtwebengineversion.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/5.4.1/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgetsVersion
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/qtwebenginewidgetsversion.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.pro
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/core/qtwebengine.gypi
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/core/qtwebengine_extras.gypi
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/core/qtwebenginecoreglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/api/qtwebengineglobal.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/api/qtwebengineglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/api/qtwebengineglobal_p.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/doc/qtwebengine.qdocconf
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/doc/src/qtwebengine.qdoc
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/api/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/api/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/qtwebenginewidgets.qdocconf
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/snippets/qtwebengine_build_snippet.qdoc
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/snippets/qtwebengine_qwebenginepage_snippet.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/snippets/qtwebengine_qwebengineview_snippet.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/src/qtwebenginewidgets.qdoc
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/tools/buildscripts/gyp_qtwebengine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/tools/buildscripts/qtwebengine_utils.py
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.index
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.qhp
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.tags
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine.qch
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets/qtwebenginewidgets.index
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets/qtwebenginewidgets.qhp
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets/qtwebenginewidgets.tags
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets.qch
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$ clear
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$ find ./ -iname "*QtWebEngine*"
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine_debug.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/5.4.1/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/5.4.1/QtWebEngine/private/qtwebengineglobal_p.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineDepends
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebengineglobal.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineVersion
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebengineversion.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngine_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine_debug.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore_debug.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWebEngineProcess
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Resources/qtwebengine_locales
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Resources/qtwebengine_resources.pak
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore_debug.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/5.4.1/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineWidgetsDepends
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineWidgetsVersion
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebenginewidgetsversion.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug.la
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/experimental/libqtwebengineexperimentalplugin.dylib
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/experimental/libqtwebengineexperimentalplugin_debug.dylib
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/libqtwebengineplugin.dylib
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/libqtwebengineplugin_debug.dylib
.//5.4/Src/qtdoc/doc/src/images/qtwebengine_quicknanobrowser.jpg
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/5.4.1/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/5.4.1/QtWebEngine/private/qtwebengineglobal_p.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/qtwebengineglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/QtWebEngineVersion
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/qtwebengineversion.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/5.4.1/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgetsVersion
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/qtwebenginewidgetsversion.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.pro
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/core/qtwebengine.gypi
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/core/qtwebengine_extras.gypi
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/core/qtwebenginecoreglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/api/qtwebengineglobal.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/api/qtwebengineglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/api/qtwebengineglobal_p.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/doc/qtwebengine.qdocconf
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/doc/src/qtwebengine.qdoc
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/api/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/api/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/qtwebenginewidgets.qdocconf
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/snippets/qtwebengine_build_snippet.qdoc
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/snippets/qtwebengine_qwebenginepage_snippet.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/snippets/qtwebengine_qwebengineview_snippet.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/src/qtwebenginewidgets.qdoc
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/tools/buildscripts/gyp_qtwebengine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/tools/buildscripts/qtwebengine_utils.py
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.index
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.qhp
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.tags
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine.qch
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets/qtwebenginewidgets.index
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets/qtwebenginewidgets.qhp
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets/qtwebenginewidgets.tags
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets.qch
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$ clear
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$
localhost:Qt5.4.1_mobile mac$ find ./ -iname "*QtWebEngine*"
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/QtWebEngine_debug.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/5.4.1/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/5.4.1/QtWebEngine/private/qtwebengineglobal_p.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineDepends
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebengineglobal.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineVersion
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebengineversion.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngine_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngine_debug.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore_debug.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWebEngineProcess
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineCore_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Resources/qtwebengine_locales
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Resources/qtwebengine_resources.pak
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineCore_debug.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug.prl
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/5.4.1/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineWidgetsDepends
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QtWebEngineWidgetsVersion
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qtwebenginewidgetsversion.h
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets.la
.//5.4/clang_64/lib/QtWebEngineWidgets_debug.la
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/experimental/libqtwebengineexperimentalplugin.dylib
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/experimental/libqtwebengineexperimentalplugin_debug.dylib
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/libqtwebengineplugin.dylib
.//5.4/clang_64/qml/QtWebEngine/libqtwebengineplugin_debug.dylib
.//5.4/Src/qtdoc/doc/src/images/qtwebengine_quicknanobrowser.jpg
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/5.4.1/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/5.4.1/QtWebEngine/private/qtwebengineglobal_p.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/QtWebEngine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/qtwebengineglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/QtWebEngineVersion
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngine/qtwebengineversion.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/5.4.1/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgetsVersion
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/include/QtWebEngineWidgets/qtwebenginewidgetsversion.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.pro
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/core/qtwebengine.gypi
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/core/qtwebengine_extras.gypi
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/core/qtwebenginecoreglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/api/qtwebengineglobal.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/api/qtwebengineglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/api/qtwebengineglobal_p.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/doc/qtwebengine.qdocconf
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webengine/doc/src/qtwebengine.qdoc
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/api/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/api/qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/qtwebenginewidgets.qdocconf
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/snippets/qtwebengine_build_snippet.qdoc
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/snippets/qtwebengine_qwebenginepage_snippet.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/snippets/qtwebengine_qwebengineview_snippet.cpp
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/doc/src/qtwebenginewidgets.qdoc
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/tools/buildscripts/gyp_qtwebengine
.//5.4/Src/qtwebengine/tools/buildscripts/qtwebengine_utils.py
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.index
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.qhp
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine/qtwebengine.tags
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebengine.qch
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets/qtwebenginewidgets.index
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets/qtwebenginewidgets.qhp
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets/qtwebenginewidgets.tags
.//Docs/Qt-5.4/qtwebenginewidgets.qch
```

the resources is not available under android_armv5/ android_armv7/.
If I import the Webengine in the QML, it still shows that the file is not available for Android. I installed my Qt SDK from here
http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.0/qt-opensource-mac-x64-android-ios-5.4.0.dmg.
  So how can I use Qt Webview to browse some pages ? I don't want to use the "JNI" ways to invoke the native SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Qt WebEngine is only supported on desktop platforms. It's not supported on iOS and Android.

On iOS it's prohibited to use other web view than Apple's. I'm not sure why WebEngine isn't supported on Android. Perhaps it's not suitable for touch interaction. Anybody knows the official reasoning for that?

Comment: Here's a thread on it: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-September/013169.html <gist> The initial release of Qt for Android is not going to include any integration 
of a web view (of sorts) into Qt Quick2 - unfortunately. This is not because 
nobody wants it, but it is simply a limitation of resources on our side and 
nobody else seems to have stepped up so far to look into it.</gist>