# Qt WebKit On Android

Tags: qt

I am trying to display a webpage in my Android app using QT 5.4. Below is the code which I am using-

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView(parent);
view->load(QUrl("http://google.com/"));
view->show();
```

and in .pro file I have added-

```
QT += qml quick widgets webkit webkitwidgets
```

Now the problem is, the code works fine on Linux desktop, but gives compilation error due to webkit webkitwidgets in my .pro file when I complie it for Android. It says Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets webkit

I have tried QtWebEngine (modified code of minibrowser from examples of QT) and placed my local html file in the project. That runs fine again on my linux desktop, but when I run it on Nexus 7 it gives me below error-

```
The webpage at qrc:/app.html could not be loaded because:
net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Please help..

Comment: I have the code ready in html/css and it works fine. I am just looking out on how to port it on mobile i.e. andorid/ios/windows. Thought QT would be a great option. But got this error in very first phase..please help..

Comment: It's not supporter and it won't be as it is discontinued in favor of web engine. So, no, it doesn't work and it will not work in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt WebKit On Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785554/qt-webkit-on-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

QtWebKit is not supported on Android.  To quote [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html):

> Qt for Android enables you to run Qt 5 applications on devices with
>   Android v2.3.3 (API level 10) or later. All Qt modules (essential and
>   add-on) are supported except **Qt WebKit**, Qt NFC, Qt Serial Port,
>   and the platform-specific ones (Qt Mac Extras, Qt Windows Extras, and
>   Qt X11 Extras).

Emphasis mine.

It's worth noting that QtWebKit is a deprecated module; it's no longer updated and will be removed in the near future.  New code should either be using [QtWebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html) on platforms where it's supported, or the [native WebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html) on Android and iOS.

Comment: I have tried QtWebEngine (modified code of minibrowser from examples of QT) and placed my local html file in the project. That runs fine again on my linux desktop, but when I run it on Nexus 7 it gives me below error-

The webpage at qrc:/app.html could not be loaded because:
net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Answer (score -1):

Try compile your own Qt5 for android with qtwebkit included (till to Qt5.5.1 it is possible).
http://wiki.qt.io/Android